# Fading dynamic forms using dynamic button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was creating my own cms using php css mysql and js. I already created a lot and stuck in a place. It is a comment reply. Consider below example.

This is 1st comment
      
Reply Button

This is 2nd comment
      
 Reply Button

When user click a reply button a form should fadeid.

The problem is that reply button and form depends on number of comment.

That way php and html gives dynamic ids to both form and button.

And it worked great. (Everything fine in html php css)

But when came to js, Manually setting ids( example $("#form1") ) works however if dynamically setting button id and form id (example $("#form"+variable)) given by php and html, it doesnt work.

For live site go here. 
http://gamerli.tk/cms/cms/post.php?post=1

Here is my form and button which is under while loop in php. Please note that class i have given to form i.e. form-ajax (inside div) has display as none, as initially it will display nothing.

```
<!-- this form is in while loop of php while runs until all comments on a specific post is completed -->

<-! Php variable comment_id is responsible for dynamic form and button id -->

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="butn-ajax-toggle<?php echo$comment_id; ?>">Reply</button>

        <div class="form-ajax" id="form-ajax<?php echo $comment_id; ?>">

        <form action="rep-submit.php" method="post">

            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="text" name="rep_author" id="rep_author" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" required>

                                </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">

                                            <input type="email" name="rep_email" id="rep_email" placeholder="Your Email" class="form-control" required>

                                </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">

                                            <input type="text" name="rep_title" id="rep_title" placeholder="Comment title (optional)" class="form-control">

                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">

                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="rep_comment" name ="rep_comment"rows="3" placeholder="Your comment" required></textarea>

                                    </div>

                                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo$comment_id; ?>" id ="rep_to">

                                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $postp_id; ?>" id ="rep_post_id">

                                   <input id="repsub" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">

                                   </form>

                                        </div>
```

Here is my js

```
// variable count is array having some integers transferred from php code to js and its working

// variable button holds dynamic ids of buttons

// variable form holds dynamic ids of forms

    var btn = [];

    var form = [];

    var limit = count.length - 1;

    for (var i = 0; i <= limit; i++)

    {

        btn[i] = "#butn-ajax-toggle"+count[i];

        form[i] = "#form-ajax"+count[i];

        $(btn[i]).click(function() {

            $(form[i]).css("display", "block");

        if ($(form[i]).css("display") == "none")

        {

            $(form[i]).fadeIn("slow");

            alert("fadein"); // added this to test whether it(if condition)  is working or not

            return false;

        }

        else

        {

            $(form[i]).fadeOut("slow");

            alert("fadeout"); //added this and seems else function is working but no form is fadingout.

            return false;

        }

    });

    }
```

Pleasr help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ["on"](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamic added elements.

In the button eventHandler is no form defined. Get the next form with:

```
var $nextForm = $(this).next(".form-ajax");
```

Code:

```
$(btn[i]).on("click", function() { //Use "on" for dynamic added elements
  var $nextForm = $(this).next(".form-ajax"); //Get next form to button

  if ($nextForm.css("display") === "none" || !$nextForm.css("display")) { 
    $nextForm.fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
  } else {
    $nextForm.fadeOut("slow");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice if condition is working when form is not displayed but, when I click button form doesnt get fadein however i get alert fadein

Comment: alright i adder alert(form[i]) in if condition, and i get result as undefined, while above if condition array for has valued

Comment: Edited my answer